# I want to Create view table by getting data from three SQL tables. But the issue is Same Column names are not Showing in table

Tags: sql, database

I want to Create view table by getting data from three SQL tables. But the issue is Same Column names are not Showing in table. When i try to run Query is SQL there is an error.

table A and Table C have one same column Name, Table B have Different Column name.
My SQL Query

```
CREATE VIEW reporting AS 
SELECT 
    chart_entery.booking_id, 
    chart_entery.activity_name, 
    tbl_booking.ref_no 
FROM proof a 
JOIN tbl_booking b 
JOIN chart_entery c 
WHERE 
    a.booking_id = b.id 
    AND a.booking_id = c.booking_id 
    AND b.id = c.booking_id
```

Error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'chart_entery.booking_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aliasing the tables, hence you need to uses the aliases when listing the columns. Also you would need to move the joining conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the relevant `JOIN`:

```
CREATE VIEW reporting AS 
SELECT 
    c.booking_id, 
    c.activity_name, 
    b.ref_no 
FROM proof a 
JOIN tbl_booking b ON  a.booking_id = b.id 
JOIN chart_entery c ON a.booking_id = c.booking_id AND b.id = c.booking_id
```

Comment: CREATE VIEW reporting AS SELECT
    c.booking_id,
    c.activity_name,
    b.ref_no,
    c.adult,
    c.child,
    c.a_v_cost,
    c.c_cost,
    c.mrk_up_amnt,
    c.mrk_up_child_amnt,
    c.vat_amnt_adult,
    c.vat_amnt_chld,
    a.ref_no
    
FROM
    proof a
JOIN tbl_booking b ON
    a.booking_id = b.id
JOIN chart_entery c ON
    a.booking_id = c.booking_id AND b.id = c.booking_id

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.ref_no' in 'field list'

Comment: What should i do now?

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: @FloapFrnd: there is no column named `a.ref_no` in my query (there is a column named `b.ref_no`). Please run the query as it is in my answer and share the result.

Comment: Actually i need  some record from table Proof .. there is also a ref no and payment received . how i can select that one

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same table alias and apply proper ON clause

```
CREATE VIEW reporting AS 
SELECT c.booking_id
    , c.activity_name
    , b.ref_no 
FROM proof a 
JOIN tbl_booking b ON a.booking_id = b.id AND
JOIN chart_entery c ON a.booking_id = c.booking_id  AND b.id = c.booking_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` is correct.  You need the corresponding `ON` clauses.  In addition, use meaning table aliases:

```
CREATE VIEW reporting AS
    SELECT ce.booking_id, ce.activity_name, b.ref_no
    FROM proof p JOIN
         tbl_booking b
         ON p.booking_id = b.id JOIN
         chart_entry ce 
         ON ce.booking_id = b.id ;
```

Your query is also messed up because of the inconsistent use of table aliases.